# Sending and receiving iOS app data via text message

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to be able to send some JSON data from one instance of my iOS app via text message to another device. Then, I want the receiving device to be able to open this data and have the instance of my app on their device consume the JSON that was sent.

So far, I'm seeing that deep-linking using the built-in app delegate function only allows me to pass in a URL, and not static data. I know I can send the data using an MFMessageComposeViewController, but am a bit lost at what to do on the receiving device end to consume this data.

Comment: If you need to senda data over to another device it would be easier to use Firebase storage

Comment: I considered that, but I would love to be able to keep the database out of it. I am thinking of using a json representation of my objects, serializing it to data, and passing the encoded string in a url that I'll use in the deep-link and then unwrap it all on the other device's side.

I'll have to see if I can hide the size of the url in the message to prevent a huge ugly url from being shown. I might have to end up using firebase though